# Java JTextArea not resetting values

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm not sure if it's actually a JTextArea problem or ActionListener or something else.

What my program does is it gets details from a given URL, and shows it in a JTextArea when the button is pressed. Here's the code I have problems with:

```
public void displayResults(String url, JTextArea area) {
    
    //number of episode
    int num = 1;
    
    //Get the URL from JTextField that will be passed as a parameter of this method
    webData.setup(url);
    
    String result = "";
    
    for (int i = 0; i < webData.getDates().size(); i++) {
        result += "Episode " + num++ + ": " + webData.getEpisodeTitle().get(i) + "\n" + "Air date: "
                + webData.getDates().get(i) + "\n\n";
    }
    //Set the text of JTextArea with the values produced in loop above
    area.setText(result);
}
```

And ActionListener:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == submitButton && !urlField.getText().equals("")) {
        displayResults(urlField.getText(), resultsTextArea);
    }
```

The problem is that every time a new URL is provided, it displays the results of the previous URL as well. For example, if I run the program and give it URL #1, it will display 20 results (let's assume it has 20 results), and when the next URL is provided, it will still display the previous 20 results from URL #1 and then display the results of URL #2 from 21. Like This:

```
Episode 22: Not aired yet!
Air date: 18 May 2018

Episode 23: The Flash Reborn
Air date: 10 Oct. 2017
```

^These are results of two different URLS. I want the URL #2 results to start from num=1, rather than increment where the URL #1 left off. Is there a way to RESET the JTextArea values every time the button is pressed? I'm really new to this so any help will be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: here's the method for webData.setup()

```
public void setup(String url) {
    
    try {
        site = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    dateData = site.select("div.airdate");
    titleData = site.select("a[itemprop='name']");
    showTitle = site.select("a.subnav_heading").first();
    
    for(Element results : dateData) {
        dates.add(results.text());
    }
    
    for(Element results : titleData) {
        if(results.text().contains("Episode #")) {
            episodeTitles.add("Not aired yet!");
        } else {
            episodeTitles.add(results.text());
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: maybe the problem might be in the ```webData.setup(url);``` method. Can you post its source?

Comment: Hello. I have added that method in the edited main post since I ran out of characters posting it here. But that's not the problem. I have tested it before using a main method in it's own class and it didn't produce any repetations. The problem only occurs when I run multiple URLs from the GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is right here

```
for(Element results : dateData) {
    dates.add(results.text());
}
```

You're adding new `Element` instances to `dates` but never removing them.
Just add

```
dates.clear();
```

before `webData.setup(url);`

so

```
public void displayResults(String url, JTextArea area) {

    //number of episode
    int num = 1;
    dates.clear();

    //Get the URL from JTextField that will be passed as a parameter of this method
    webData.setup(url);

    String result = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < webData.getDates().size(); i++) {
        result += "Episode " + num++ + ": " + webData.getEpisodeTitle().get(i) + "\n" + "Air date: "
                + webData.getDates().get(i) + "\n\n";
    }
    //Set the text of JTextArea with the values produced in loop above
    area.setText(result);
}
```

Comment: @CharmingPotato if it worked, you should upvote and accept my answer :) thank you, glad I helped

Comment: I did, but it won't let me vote since I don't have 15 reputation :(